# Github pages, bootstrap css remotely: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, github-pages

I have my customized bootstrap website which I push on github pages. Locally it works very fine, no problem at all, but when is online the style is messy and these messages appear on the console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)   https://nickname.github.io/repo/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

in my code, css is declared as follow:

```
<link href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

why locally works and not remotely?

Comment: Try change like this href="~/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using Jekyll for your GitHub page. As for the Jekyll 3.3 from Nov 2016, [the vender folder is ignored](https://github.com/blog/2277-what-s-new-in-github-pages-with-jekyll-3-3).

> Jekyll now ignores the vendor and node_modules directories by default.

You can either rename the `vender` folder to some name like `libs` and refer to the new path, or follow Jekyll's [suggestion](https://github.com/blog/2277-what-s-new-in-github-pages-with-jekyll-3-3)

> If you need those directories included in your site, set exclude: [] in your site's configuration file.

Hope it helps:)

Answer (score 3):

Thank you all. The problem was that recently Github updated to Jekyll v3.3, which ignores vendored files by default. As I was not using Jekyll for my Pages site, I had to add a .nojekyll file to the root of my repository to disable Jekyll from building my site. Once I did that, my site built with my vendored files without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure the path with css's is not empty on your server ,You need to use `~/` in HTML href, let me explain

1. / - `href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"` - it is site root
2. ~/ - `href="~/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"` -it is root directory of your  application

`/` should return the root of the site (https://nickname.github.io/repo/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css),

`~/` should return the root of the application (https://nickname.github.io/ROOTDIR/repo/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css).

Comment: Hello mww, thank you for your answer.  I tried what explain me but no way. You can see my code on github https://github.com/ValeC/portfolio-valentina-coletti.git

Comment: @Colet I check your code and you have to use "~/" or "./"  and it must  to work properly.